# Confusion Over Geometric Irreducibility

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$. For an extension field $K$ of $k$, we can change the base to obtain the scheme $X_K$. Supposedly it is possible that $X$ is irreducible while $X_K$ is reducible, indeed this leads to the notion of geometric irreducibility.

I am having trouble understanding this from a topological point of view. The way we define the base change is as the fiber product with respect to the maps $X\to Spec(k)$ and $Spec(K)\to Spec(k)$, but in particular this object $X_K$ is a fiber product in the category of topological spaces. As $Spec(K)$ and $Spec(k)$ are one point spaces, the pullback ought to simply be $X$. How can it be that the pullback $X_K$ is not homeomorphic to $X$?

I realize it is probably a very simple error I am making here.

Comment: Do an example. Take for example $X=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$, $k=\mathbb R$ and $K=\mathbb C$.

Comment: Right, I understand how, algebraically, these things can stop being reducible. But a fiber product of $X$ and a single point over a single point ought to just be $X$, if we are simply thinking of topological spaces, right?

Comment: Well, wrong (for otherwise my example would have to give an irreducible space)! In particular, the underlying topological space of a fiber product of schemes it is not the fiber product of the unlerlying topological spaces. A simple instance of this is the well-known fact that the topology of $\mathbb A^2$ is not the cartesian product of two copies of $\mathbb A^1$.

Comment: OK, that is my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please add a nice answer explaining the issue :-)

Comment: What's an example of something becoming *irreducible* after base change?

Comment: You can take a scheme with two irreducible components and base change along the inclusion of one component. You will get the one component. Of course, when the base change is along a universally injective ring map (e.g. faithfully flat), this phenomenon does not occur: a subring of an integral domain is integral.

Comment: Dear rondo9: it is impossible (as noticed by @Hoot and Remy)  to go from reducible to irreducible **by an extension of fields**. Please correct your sentence  *"Supposedly it is possible that $X$ is reducible while $X_K$ is irreducible"*: you have mixed up the adjectives *reducible* and *irreducible*.

Answer (score 0):

I was making an error, from  which I learn something important. Fiber products in the category of Schemes are *not* fiber products in the category of Topological Spaces. Since there are more objects and more morphisms in $\mathfrak{Top}$, a fiber product in that category has to be universal for more stuff than a fiber product in the category $\mathfrak{Sch}$, so even though the diagram looks the same, the universality is what is changing things here.

Comment: Another thing to say is that it's not a matter of there being more continuous maps, it's that a morphism of schemes has extra data. This is something new -- a map of topological spaces or manifolds is determined by what happens on the "set points" and in the category of schemes that's no longer true.